# xcode 8 automatically indentation for @property

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Not sure if happening to anyone else but if some setting was changed when I upgraded to Xcode 8, but all my @property is automatically indented in @interface. Seems even if I ctrl+I to reindent it, it automatically tabs infront of @property. So, two part question, is everyone else seeing this, and if anyone knows how to fix it (or is this the new convention)?

Comment: Do you have a question? So far this is just a statement of what you are seeing (which everyone else is seeing too).

Comment: Yes, sorry i was going to ask if other people are seeing and also is there any way of fixing it.

Comment: I'm seeing it.  I'm trying to figure out if it's an intentional change in how indentation works, along the lines of how Swift indents, or if it's just a bug.  I find it interesting that it also wants to indent @@end so that it is not at the same level as @@interface.  Feels like a bug.

Comment: I see the same, and not only for `@property`. It now wants to indent everything between `@implementation` and `@end` as well. Pretty annoying. Please issue a bug on bugreport.apple.com for it.

Answer (score 3):

This has helped me. Xcode --> Preferences... --> Text Editing --> Indentation --> Automatic indent for --> uncheck ";" and return.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this is **not** a "Thank you" answer. There are no other answers here, and the solution provided is not mentioned in comments either.